# Определение региона по номеру телефона на сайте

Tags: php

Как на сайте определить регион по введенному пользователем номеру?

Comment: ручками писать if'ы

Comment: Как вам больше нравится - хоть через if, хоть через switch, хоть через список.

Comment: Я немного не понимаю вашу логику. А с чем вы предлагаете сравнивать номер @Эникейщик

Comment: Вы уже забыли собственный вопрос? С номером, который ввёл пользователь.

Comment: Вы, наверное, неправильно поняли. Мне нужно определить регион набранного номера.@Эникейщик

Comment: Вот и определяйте. В чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка на сайт с телефонными кодами: https://phonenum.info/country-code/

Пропарсите информацию в два массива и ищите совпадения первых символов в нём. Потом по индексу обращайтесь ко второму и печатайте ответ.